# Retrieve view inside a row of a ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a listview with 4 identical rows. Inside those rows, I have a RelativeLayout which contains a TextView (id : R.id.notif). In my Activity, I use my own ArrayAdapter.

I would like to be able to modify the text of the third row. I tried this but it isn't working.

```
((TextView)listview.getAdapter().getView(2, null, listview).findViewById(R.id.notif)).setText("50");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `adapter.getView()` for that! This method is used internally for the adapter to create the view that gets displayed in the list! The correct way to do this is to modify the underlying data and to refresh the list with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Do not try to access views in the list directly, you don't know if they are visible at the moment or scrolled outside the view.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: You'll find plenty of examples when you google for something like "android listview adapter change data" or similar

Comment: Yes, anyway I tried something and it's working like a charm, thank you :)